# How to access a number within a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If i have a list like

```
list=[1 ,22, 4 ,18, 42]
```

how do I add 1 to each number that has a 2 in it? So in this case the output would be

```
[1 ,23, 4 ,18, 43]
```

Is there a way I can do this by checking if each number within the list contains a 2?

Comment: use a loop, check if the number containes a "2" and count up if so.

Comment: Would you consider 25 to have a 2 in it?

Comment: Yes. I would consider 25 to have a two in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can check `'2'` in `str` each number then plus one like below:

*(better don't use [`built-in function`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) like `list` as variable name)*

```
>>> lst1 = [1 ,22, 4 ,18, 42]
>>> [item +1 if '2' in str(item) else item for item in lst1]
[1, 23, 4, 18, 43]
```

Shorter Version by thanks @user2390182:

```
>>> [item + ("2" in str(item)) for item in lst1]
[1, 23, 4, 18, 43] # <-> [1+0 , 22+1, 4+0, 18+0, 42+1]

# for more explanation
>>> [("2" in str(item)) for item in lst1]
[False, True, False, False, True] # <-> [0,1,0,0,1]
```

Comment: what is wrong with built-in functions ?

Comment: if you use built-in function as a variable if you call built-in function you get an error

Comment: @zedling here you got error :`len = 3; a=[1,2]; len(a)` : `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` because you use built-in function as variable

Comment: Or shorter: `[item + ("2" in str(item)) for item in lst1]` ;-)

Comment: @user2390182 very good shortest approach

Comment: Well illustrated!

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [1,22,4,18,42]
for i in range(len(list)):
    if '2' in str(list[i]):
        list[i]+=1
```

in for loop. check '2' and add one.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that filters the numbers by the conditions and adds the required value to it, which you can use with the `map` function to iterate through the list.

```
def add_to_list(num):
    if "2" in str(num):
        return num + 1
    else:
        return num

list_1 = [1 ,22, 4 ,18, 42]

new_list = list(map(add_to_list, list_1))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the list and typecast each number to `string`. That way you can easily use the `in` operator to check if 2 is present in that string.

(I am creating a new list for updated values since we might need old values for some other task, but we can do in-place updation as well)

```
number_list = [1 ,22, 4 ,18, 42]
updated_list = []

for number in number_list:
    if '2' in str(number):
        updated_list.append(number + 1)
    else:
        updated_list.append(number)
```

Answer (score -2):

Cycle through the list with a `for` loop and add an `if` condidition inside the loop. Something like this:

```
if 2 in list_item:
    list_item=list_item+1
```